# Getting 503 / 404 errors trying to access Google Groups API to get settings

Tags: google-groups-api

I'm trying to use the RESTful method to retrieve A Google Groups settings, but all I get is 503 or 404 errors, or backend error messages.  I'm using the following URL:
https://www.googleapis.com/groups/v1/groups/{my email address}
Does this even work?

I'm using the oauth2 gem and Ruby, the code works for the calendar but not the groups:

`groupdata = access_token.get('https.//www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{my email address}').parsed`

`groupdata = access_token.get('https.//www.googleapis.com/groups/v1/groups/{my email address}').parsed`

I'm defining the scope for the groups call as "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.groups.settings"

Comment: Yes, it works. Can you share your code?

Comment: If I try it through the Google API Explorer webpage I get a 503 error, through my code I get a Backend error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `{my email address}` is the primary address of a user not a group?

You need to specify the primary email address of a group to query the group's settings.

Also, the Groups Settings API only works for Google Groups for Business. It will not work for consumer Google Groups (@googlegroups.com address) or Google Apps Free/Standard Edition.

Comment: I should clarify that I am using the group's email address not a user's

Comment: Thanks.  SHould it work with the trial version?  I'm getting a "Domain cannot use Apis." message